# Can't bind to a propery since it isn't a known property of a specific component

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, two-way-binding

`I did this in the Angular html file:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
     <app-add-edit-dep [dep]="dep" *ngIf="ActivateAddEditDepComp">
     </app-add-edit-dep>
    </div>
```

Now the error is:
Error: src/app/department/show-dep/show-dep.component.html:23:31 - error NG8002:
Can't bind to 'dep' since it isn't a known property of 'app-add-edit-dep'.

1. If 'app-add-edit-dep' is an Angular component and it has 'dep' input, then verify that it is part of this module.     `your text`
2. If 'app-add-edit-dep' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.'

This is the Angular TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-dep',
  templateUrl: './show-dep.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-dep.component.css']
})
export class ShowDepComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:SharedService) { }

  DepartmentList:any=[];

  ActivateAddEditDepComp:boolean=false;
  dep:any;
  ModalTitle:string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshDepList();
  }

  addClick(){
    this.dep={
      DepartmentId:0,
      DepartmentName:""
    }
    this.ModalTitle="Add Department";
    this.ActivateAddEditDepComp=true;
  }

  closeClick(){
    this.ActivateAddEditDepComp=false;
    this.refreshDepList();
  }


  refreshDepList(){
    this.service.getDepList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.DepartmentList=data;
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error given to you by Angular outlines the most likely causes. It could be that you aren't importing the `AddEditDepComponent` (or similarly named) into the module where you are declaring `ShowDepComponent`. As per the message, it could also be that the `dep` input is not declared - either because you've missed the `Input()` decorator, or because it just doesn't exist as a proper on that class at all.

Comment: Hi I added the @Input()
  dep: any; in app-add-edit-dep, but still the error remains.

Comment: @sarangish Are you very sure that AddEditDepComponent is unique? I recognized your problem and my fault was I accidentally had 2 components with exactly the same name.

Comment: @Jojoseph Hi, I solved it, the problem was I was using Bootstrap CDN. I just installed bootstrap using npm install.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a property "dep" in add-edit-dep component with the decorator @Input()

Input [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Input).

Comment: Hi thank u for replying, but that didn't solve it. I saw this suggetion inthe terminal error panel - 'To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.' Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need be sure that your app-add-edit-dep is declared in app.module.ts (or another needed *.module.ts).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ShowDepComponent } from './show-dep/show-dep.component';
import { AddEditDepComponent } from './add-edit-dep/add-edit-dep.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ShowDepComponent,
    AddEditDepComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The second reason, can be that "dep" property  of app-add-edit-dep doesnt have @Input() anatation, like

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-dep',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-dep.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-dep.component.css']
})
export class AddEditDepComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  dep: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: Hai, thank u Nikita for the reply,  but  - @Input() dep: any;   is not working for me unfortunately. If not bothering you, is there any other solutions..

Comment: Hello @sarangish
Could you share app-add-edit-dep component code in order to help you

Comment: hai Nikita, If you're asking the app-add-edit-dep TS component, its the same code you have answered above (2nd one). - @sarangish

Comment: @sarangish Could you tell, how many *.module.ts does your project have? If there are several ones, the issue can be link with the modules don't have proper importing(or exporting)

Comment: Only one app.module.ts..

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same tutorial. You just have to declare in the add-edit-dep.components.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-dep',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-dep.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-dep.component.css']
})
export class AddEditDepComponent {

 @Input() dep:any;   <------ THIS WOULD ENABLE TO RUN THE APP

}
```

Comment: Giving -  @Input() dep:any; -  is not working bro. I tried this, as all the answers above signifies the same solution. Any other suggeston? (Thanks by the way)